# Product displaying in subcategory but not in the category

Tags: magento, e-commerce, categories

I have a product in Magento in the subcategory ("1a") that shows fine when I browse to that category in the front end but won't show when I browse to its mother category ("1"), and I want it to be shown there too.

In the backend, both the category and subcategory have "anchor" enabled. The products are enabled and visible in catalog, search.

I have checked the following on the advice of the post below, but this is all ok for me, especially it is displaying in the subcategory but not in the category where it says there are no products matching selection.

The checklist for whether items are in stock follows. Some will seem stupid until the first time you spend an hour trying to figure this problem out:

- The products must be Visible in Catalog.
- The products must be Enabled.
- Product must have a stock Quantity.
- The product must be set to In Stock.
- If the product is set not to track stock, it still has to have a stock Quantity and be set to In Stock.
- The product must be assigned to the target Category.
- If using multi-website mode (or if you imported the products through Data Flow), the products must be assigned to the target Website.
- You must refresh your Cache / Indices, just to make sure.

Comment: Do you have both categories checked?

Comment: this is not needed....only the subcategory needs to be checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you've got everything correct. Sometimes the categories can get wonky - I'm not really sure why. If you go to your categories page - drag your subcategory out of the parent and then back in it might help.

I usually follow the exact same steps you were given by Joe. Whenever I run into this issue it is usually solved by one of the following. I would double check these things (especially the indexes) just in case.

1. Index's need to be refreshed. (Depending on your site indexing can take a while - and sometimes products will not be shown as the catalog is re-indexed).
2. Cache needs to be refreshed.
3. My category structure is not what I thought it was.

I hope that helps. Any extra information you can provide would certainly be helpful as well.

Comment: wow, yeah just moving the subcat to another place and moving it inside again made it work!!! Thanks!

Comment: I'll have to remember this...didn't know.

Comment: yes it's solved problem but after sometime problem again arises we cannot check store every time if there is problem.